# SP 2019 - Onpremise - Userprofiles - names removed from AD but still appear in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile-service

My users which have been removed from AD are still showing up in SP. I notice the mysites are still there for these users as well. I am not expert at all and seem to find issues in user profile sync.

There is no trouble on the import - all new users are added. I have approximately 390 users but the sync is showing 475 - significantly more. Some guidance as to where to begin to troubleshoot would be most appreciated.

As mentioned using SP2019 on premise (no azure) - Userprofile synchronization connection using Active Directory Import.

Answer (score 1):

Run this SQL query against the Profile database to check if deleted users have been marked:

```
Select * From upa.UserProfile_Full Where bDeleted = 1
```

Then run the **My Site Cleanup Job**. After the job runs, it schedules the profiles to be deleted after 30 days,The 30-day setting is hard-coded. There is no way to change it. Also, if your build is pre-August 2017 CU (16.0.4573.1002), this functionality does not work at all, even after 30 days.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spses/sharepoint-2016-mysitecleanup-job-functionality-changes

https://joshroark.com/sharepoint-the-complete-guide-to-user-profile-cleanup-part-4-2016/

Comment: Thanks for this Julie. I have run the query against the upa.UserProfile_Full and no results come up. If I run the query and set the bDeleted = 0 all my users show up - including the ones which are removed from AD. Unless I manually remove the users under SP CA they still appear.

Comment: It seems that UPA does not recognized some users has been removed from AD, try to create a new connection, run full sync, and compare the result.